# Improvments for this scipt to restart each running systemd service?

Tags: systemd

I have Centos 7+ systems, and they all use systemd. Sometimes the best way to proceed after an important system change is to restart each currently running service. If I restart each service one-at-a-time, then the system generally stays online, and it is very easy to see service problems as they appear.
So I hacked out this little bash script, which restarts each running systemd service, EXCEPT certain named services which I think are core to keeping the box online.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
running=$(systemctl list-units --type service | grep running \
    | grep -iv audit \
    | grep -iv disk \
    | grep -iv drive \
    | grep -iv getty \
    | grep -iv irq \
    | grep -iv libstoragemgt \
    | grep -iv lvm \
    | grep -iv multipath \
    | grep -iv polkit \
    | grep -iv storage \
    | cut -d' ' -f1)

for service in $running ; do
    echo "$service"
    systemctl restart "$service"
done
```

There are several things I wish were better:

- Grepping for "running" is a crude way to filter for running tasks, and the multiple pipes are pretty expensive.
- Using `cut` is really brittle, and breaks when the output format
  of systemd changes.
- `systemctl restart` does not set a return code on start failure, so the script keeps going even if a service fails to stop or start.

What may be some better ways to to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve your code you can do the following:

1. use systemctl's `--state running` instead of `grep running` to filter the services you nees.
2. use `grep -v -f exclude-services.list` instead of a chain of `grep`'s
3. use `systemctl try-restart s1 s2 s3 ...` all at once instead of looping through the list.

First list the services to be excluded in `exclude-services.list`:

```
potom@vm /tmp $ cat exclude-services.list 
audit.service
disk.service
drive.service
getty.service
irq.service
libstoragemgt.service
lvm.service
multipath.service
polkit.service
storage.service
```

Then this script should work:

```
potom@vm /tmp $ cat restart-all.sh
RESTART_SERVICES=$(systemctl list-units --type service --state running | \
    awk '$1 ~ /\.service/{print $1}' | \
    grep -v -f exclude-services.list )

systemctl try-restart ${RESTART_SERVICES}
```

That may be a little more robust than your script. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

> What may be some better ways to do this?

**Reboot the server :)**

Restarting all services is rarely a good idea. Either you are updating the whole system and then you want to make sure you that everything uses the latest patched libraries. Or you are updating / reconfiguring just one service and then a simple `systemctl reload whatever.service` should be enough, no need to restart all running services.

Besides it's a good idea to reboot the server from time to time to ensure that it actually *is* rebootable. I have seen servers with years of uptime that no one dares to reboot because no one knows if they will actually come back up, what changes have been made and not saved, etc.

If it is a *critical system* it is surely in some High-Availability cluster and rebooting one node won't matter. If it is *not a critical system* you can reboot it, even if after business hours or over the weekend.

So to answer your question - **reboot the server**

Comment: Well, yes. Some of these are critical, if they do down, we loose all external network, or logins, or media services. But no, there not not a single cluster anywhere in the organization. Think "Public K-12 School District" and "Volunteer IT Department" and "Donated Equipment".

Comment: @Charlweed if it's a school you can always reboot the server after hours. Better than fiddling with the settings during school hours. You can schedule the reboot with `at` / `atd` command, e.g. `echo reboot | at 5:00PM`, and you won't have to stick around to execute it. See https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm for more about `at` command.

Comment: I hear ya potom. Wed. and weekends are reboot  days. The "Normal" thing to to is reboot. My issue here is for crunch situations, when they call the volunteers at our real jobs, off site. And Thanks.